# Laravel Echo Server throwing "Cannot set property 'socketId' of undefined"

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

If I connect on a public channel it all works just fine. But if I connect on a presence or private channel I get the following error every time.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectiionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: [some number]): TypeError: Cannot set your property 'socketId' of undefined.

After which point I no longer receive any events broadcasted to the user. The users are authenticated and joined to listen to the channel but they don't receive any events.

I am using Laravel Echo Server 1.3 with Laravel 5.4 and Laravel Echo JS

Here is a screen grab of what I get:

[image: Laravel Echo Server SocketId undefined]

Anyone know what causes this and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance!